# C++ function only goes thru the for loop once

Tags: c++, debugging

so I've got integers `m` and `n` in my program, once you input the values it should create an array with values from `m` to `n` (for example `m = 1` and `n = 10`, it creates array `q` with values from 1 to 10). Then it looks in the array if there are any numbers that are equal to any two number sum that are squared (for example, in the array, number 2 is equal to 1 squared + 1 squared). The problem is the program only gives out the first found result, as an example let's take 1 and 10 again, it only out prints 2 = 1 * 1 + 1 * 1, it should go thru the for loop again and find out that 5 = 2 * 2 + 1 * 1 etc etc. Is it even possible to do with a function that begins with int?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int squared (int m, int n, int* M)
{
    int result;
    for(int i= 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j= 0; j < n; j++)
            for(int k= 0; k < n; k++)
                if( (M[i] == ( (M[j] * M[j]) + (M[k] * M[k]) ))) 
                {
                    result = ( (M[j] * M[j]) + (M[k] * M[k]) );
                    cout << result << endl;
                    return result; // if success we return result
                }

    return -1; 
}

int main ()
{
    int n, m, size;

    do
    {
        cout <<"m: ";
        cin >> m;
        cout << "n: ";
        cin >> n;

        if(n <= 0 || m <= 0)
            cout <<"You can't input an integer that is 0 or below: ";

        if(m >= n)
            cout << "n must be greater than m!" << endl;
    }while (m <= 0 || n <= 0 || m >= n);

    size = n - m; 
    int* M = new int[n - m]; 


    for(int i= 0, j = m; i <= size; i++, j++)
        M[i] = j;


    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        cout << M[i] << ", " ;
    cout << endl;


    cout << squared(m, n, M) << endl;


    delete[] M;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, and single stepped through each statement, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: Rather than using a dynamically allocated array, you may want to create a `std::vector`.

Comment: Off-Topic:  Variable names differing only in case, such as 'm' and 'M', is a bad programming practice.  You have at least 32 letters for variable names, so use them.

Comment: `squared` function returns immediately when found the result, and you call this function just once. So the real question is what loop you're talking about.

Comment: Another point separate from what you are asking. You are overrunning your buffer in multiple places by doing : ````i <= size;````. Arrays are zero-indexed and thus an index equal to the size is 1 past the end of the array.

Comment: `if( (M[i] == ( (M[j] * M[j]) + (M[k] * M[k]) )))` wow, no wonder I had trouble finding parentheses today: you used them all up. `if( M[i] == M[j] * M[j] + M[k] * M[k])` does the same thing, without redundant parentheses.